# Check if flex datagrid column contains data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Is there a way to check if flex datagrid column is empty or not? I tried to search for a DataGridColumn that would allow me to that but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Empty?? your question is not really clear. Please clarify

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I mean by empty that it contains no data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to say that the value of that GridColumn is null for all rows then this snippet should work:

```
//myDG is the datagrid
var allNull:Boolean=true;
for each(var o:Object in myDG.dataProvider) {
    if(o.myColumnName != null) {
        allNull=false;
        break;
    }
}

trace(allNull); //false = all is not null, true = everything in that column is null
```